# Scrubbing list for non matching values in B

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-2007, pivot, matching

I would really appreciate a help on my Excel problem.

```
Column  B   Column C
Account 1   123
Account 2   234
Account 2   277
Account 3   443
Account 3   null
Account 4   null
```

I have accounts listed in column B, with sub accounts listed in column C.  When I did the data extraction some came back with a NULL.

I need to scrub the list for accounts in column B that have multiple records in column C.   So if the account as a matching value in C or a null it is fine. But if there are two different values in C I have to get rid of it.

So for the example, above I would need to scrub the list for account 2 because it has different values.

I got this work as a pivot table for my sample of 25 records, but I need a formula that will help me id and scrub the list for 16000 records.

Comment: Can you define "scrub"? What do you want to do with the two entries for Account 2?

Comment: I have to create a second list of accounts that only have one value or a value plus null.  Or put another way, I have to delete accounts that have multiple values (like account 2 above).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in row 1, then copy down, filter on TRUE values and delete visible rows.

```
=countifs(B:B,B1,C:C,"<>"&C1)>0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I didn't work for me though, as it did not isolate those accounts that have multiple values - like account 2 would need to be deleted.  I figure there is an index match thing but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand it, you want to show a list of unique account names and their values. Still not sure what you want to do with the values of duplicate account names. Please clarify.

One possible approach is with using a helper column. Into D2 put the formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B5,B5)>1,"",ROW())
```

Copy down to the end of the list. Then in F2 enter the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(D:D,ROW(A1))),"")
```

Copy down. In G2 enter

```
=IF(LEN(F2)>1,VLOOKUP(F2,B:C,2,FALSE),"")
```

Copy down. The result is a unique list of account names from column B, followed by the first value that this account has in column C.

The helper column can be hidden.

[image]